# Using references in GitHub wiki with restructured text

Tags: github, wiki, restructuredtext

I'm trying to use internal references to link an index atop my wiki page with several sections within the document. Here's an example:

```
 * `My index`_
    + Foreword_
    + `Technical details`_


 My index
 --------

 Foreword
 ~~~~~~~~

 Technical details
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I generate the HTML page via rest2html I get the right result. However, GitHub wiki inserts extra words in the references and the links do not work. for example:

```
 https://github.com/myaccount/myproject/wiki/Page#wiki-my-index
 https://github.com/myaccount/myproject/wiki/Page#wiki-foreword
 https://github.com/myaccount/myproject/wiki/Page#wiki-technical-details
```

I couldn't find any relevant document in the GitHub page, so I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the class ids are missing from the generated divs.  Check the page source to (not) see them.  I think this is what it should look like:

```
<ul>
  <li><dl class="first docutils">
    <dt><a class="reference internal" href="#my-index">My index</a></dt>
  <li><a class="reference internal" href="#foreword">Foreword</a></li>
  <li><a class="reference internal" href="#technical-details">Technical details</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="section" id="my-index">
  <h1>My index</h1>
</div>
<div class="section" id="foreword">
  <h2>Foreword</h2>
</div>
<div class="section" id="technical-details">
  <h2>Technical details</h2>
</div>
```

Edit: User intuited mentions the same issue in [a GitHub markup issue](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/6)

> I've noticed this problem with README.rst files as well. As well as
>   headings, inline targets in .rst files, e.g. _`some target`, don't
>   work. The inline target text gets wrapped in a  but doesn't get
>   made into any sort of link target. Should I file this as a separate
>   issue?

Comment: Thanks Tim! I'm subscribed to the bug.